# Why is a vendor CSS chunk get built only in production (not in my development environment)?

Tags: css, webpack, vue-cli

I have a multi page application using webpack's entry points.

When deploying the page via Netlify, this vendors chunk stylesheet is outputting to the page:

```
<link href="/css/chunk-vendors.87c094b1.css" rel="preload" as="style">
```

However, when I build and serve the files on my development environment, this asset is not present on the page.

```
yarn build
serve dist -p 8080
```

Additionally, it's batching up all the styles from all the vendors into this chunk, regardless of whether or not the styles are used in a particular entry point. Ideally, it would only include styles used in that entry point.

I haven't defined any `config.optimization.splitChunks` in `vue.config.js`.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious here. Let me know if I should include more information (e.g. particular config settings).

Answer (score 1):

Webpack doesn't create the css files in dev mode by default. To get around this you should add to your vue.config.js to your module exports

```
css: {
   extract: true,
},
```